What is the best way to fit a quadratic polynomial to p-dimensional data and compute its gradient and Hessian matrix?
I have been trying to use the scikit-learn library to solve this problem.  Roughly:
from sklearn.preprocessing import PolynomialFeatures
from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression

# Make or load an n x p data matrix X and n x 1 array y of the corresponding
# function values.

poly = PolynomialFeatures(degree=2)
Xp = poly.fit_transform(X)
model = LinearRegression()
model.fit(Xp, y)

# Approximate the derivatives of the gradient and Hessian using the relevant
# finite-difference equations and model.predict.

As the above illustrates, sklearn makes the design choice to separate polynomial regression into PolynomialFeatures and LinearRegression rather than combine these into a single function.  This separation has conceptual advantages but also a major drawback:  it effectively prevents model from offering the methods gradient and hessian, and model would be significantly more useful if it did.
My current work-around uses finite-difference equations and model.predict to approximate the elements of the gradient and Hessian (as described here).  But I don't love this approach — it is sensitive to floating-point error and the "exact" information needed to build the gradient and Hessian is already contained in model.coef_.
Is there any more elegant or accurate method to fit a p-dimensional polynomial and find its gradient and Hessian within Python? I would be fine with one that uses a different library.

To compute the gradient or the Hessian of a polynomial, one needs to know exponents of variables in each monomial and the corresponding monomial coefficients. The first piece of this information is provided by poly.powers_, the second by model.coef_:
from sklearn.preprocessing import PolynomialFeatures
from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression
import numpy as np

np.set_printoptions(precision=2, suppress=True)

X = np.arange(6).reshape(3, 2)
y = np.arange(3)
poly = PolynomialFeatures(degree=2)
Xp = poly.fit_transform(X)
model = LinearRegression()
model.fit(Xp, y)

print("Exponents:")
print(poly.powers_.T)
print("Coefficients:")
print(model.coef_)

This gives:
Exponents:
[[0 1 0 2 1 0]
 [0 0 1 0 1 2]]
Coefficients:
[ 0.    0.13  0.13 -0.12 -0.    0.13]

The following function can be then used to compute the gradient at a point given by an array x:
def gradient(x, powers, coeffs):
    x = np.array(x)
    gp = np.maximum(0, powers[:, np.newaxis] - np.eye(powers.shape[1], dtype=int))
    gp = gp.transpose(1, 2, 0)
    gc = coeffs * powers.T
    return (((x[:, np.newaxis] ** gp).prod(axis=1)) * gc).sum(axis=1)

For example, we can use it to compute the gradient at the point [0, 1]:
print(gradient([0, 1],  poly.powers_, model.coef_))

This gives:
[0.13 0.38]

The Hessian at a given point can be computed in a similar way.

You can perform symbolic differentiation to compute exact gradients and Hessians. Since the polynomial model's coefficients are known after fitting, you can directly differentiate the polynomial to get its gradient and Hessian matrices symbolically.
from numpy.random import rand
from sklearn.preprocessing import PolynomialFeatures
from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression
from sympy import symbols, prod, diff
from numpy import sum, linspace

n = 20
p = 2
X = rand(n, p)
y = rand(n)

poly = PolynomialFeatures(degree=2)
Xp = poly.fit_transform(X)
model = LinearRegression()
model.fit(Xp, y)

powers = poly.powers_
coeffs = model.coef_
syms = symbols(f'x0:{p}')

f = sum([coeffs[i]*prod(syms**powers[i]) for i in range(len(coeffs))])

Df = [diff(f, xj) for xj in syms]
H = [[diff(djf, xk) for xk in syms] for djf in Df]
print('Gradient:', Df)
print('Hessian:', H)

x0 = linspace(0.2, 0.7, p)  # test point
Df_x0 = [Df[k].evalf(subs={syms[j]:x0[j] for j in range(p)}) for k in range(p)]
print('x0:', x0)
print('Gradient at x0:', Df_x0)


This gives incorrect results, since poly_eq does not reflect the polynomial features created using sklearn. In particular, it assumes that in these features each variable appears with exponent either 0 or 1, which is not the case. Once this is fixed, it should work.

After studying various solutions to this problem, I believe the easiest method (easiest on the programmer) is to use sympy, roughly as described in Jhon's answer.  However, as bb1 notes, Jhon's answer produces incorrect results in its unedited form.  Here is one way to edit Jhon's approach to obtain correct results.
from numpy.random import rand
from sklearn.preprocessing import PolynomialFeatures
from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression

from sympy import symbols, prod, diff
from numpy import sum, linspace

n = 200
p = 4
X = rand(n, p)
y = rand(n)

poly = PolynomialFeatures(degree=2)
Xp = poly.fit_transform(X)
model = LinearRegression()
model.fit(Xp, y)

powers = poly.powers_
coeffs = model.coef_
intercept = model.intercept_
syms = symbols(f'x0:{p}')

f = intercept + sum([coeffs[i]*prod(syms**powers[i]) for i in range(len(coeffs))])

Df = [diff(f, xj) for xj in syms]
H = [[diff(djf, xk) for xk in syms] for djf in Df]
print('Gradient:', Df)
print('Hessian:', H)

x0 = linspace(0.2, 0.7, p)  # test point
Df_x0 = [Df[k].evalf(subs={syms[j]:x0[j] for j in range(p)}) for k in range(p)]
print('x0:', x0)
print('Gradient at x0:', Df_x0)

However, sympy is not necessary to compute the gradient and Hessian, as indicated by bb1's answer.  Here is a loop-based way to write bb1's answer that I find easier to read.  Note though that it may run slower than bb1's answer, so if speed is a concern, bb1's answer may be superior.
from numpy import zeros, maximum

x0 = [0, 1]

# Define p, X, y, poly, model, powers, and coeffs.

grad = zeros(p, dtype=float)
for i in range(p):
    gc = powers.T[i] * coeffs  # gradient coefficients
    gp = powers.copy()  # gradient powers
    gp[:,i] = maximum(0, gp[:,i] - 1)
    grad[i] = (gc*(x0**gp).prod(axis=1)).sum()
print('grad = ', grad)

hess = zeros((p,p), dtype=float)
for i in range(p):
    gc = powers.T[i] * coeffs
    gp = powers.copy()
    gp[:,i] = maximum(0, gp[:,i] - 1)
    for j in range(p):
        hc = gp.T[j] * gc  # Hessian coefficients
        hp = gp.copy()  # Hessian powers
        hp[:,j] = maximum(0, hp[:,j] - 1)
        hess[i][j] = (hc*(x0**hp).prod(axis=1)).sum()
hess = array(hess)
print('hess = ', hess)

